# ipython: exit() statement not working as expected

Tags: python, ipython, exit, execution, terminate

I am running a script into ipython (1.2.1) and I need it to stop if a certain condition is not met. I tried to use the exit() statement, but it is not behaving as expected.

Take for example the following script which I called `test.py`:

```
if(True):
    print('Error')
    exit()
print('Still here!')
```

When I run it using `python test.py`, I get:

```
$python test.py
Error
```

And then the execution is terminated, as expected.

But if I run it from ipython using `run -i test.py`, then I get:

```
In [1]: run -i test.py
Error
Still here!
```

And finally the execution of ipython is terminated. The problem is that in this case the second print statement is still executed, while I would need the execution of the script to be terminated as soon as the exit() statement is encountered.

Why is this happening and how can I obtain the result I want? *(I am running python 2.7.6)*

Comment: `import sys; sys.exit(0)`

Comment: I don't know ipython, but give `sys.exit()` a try. Of course you will also need to `import sys` if you haven't already done so. The plain `exit()` function is a bit strange: it's designed as a convenience for use in the standard Python interactive interpreter, but it's generally not a good idea to use it in other contexts.

Comment: update to ipython 5

Comment: @cricket_007 It works! But why exactly doesn't exit() work? If you transform your comment in an answer and explain this to me I will be glad to accept it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`exit()` alone is meant for the REPL, not really meant to be used by scripts.

Try using `sys.exit(0)` after you `import sys`, of course

Comment: In an interactive Ipython session, the REPL catches `sys.exit`.  I rely on that all the time when testing `argparse` examples.